Exporting shapefiles from QGIS to Unreal Engine
I am a beginner with QGIS and Unreal Engine.
I have a shapefile of rivers.
What steps do I need to take to export the shapefile from QGIS so that it can be utilized in Unreal Engine and align properly with the landscape to create water bodies for the rivers?
It would be ideal to use only the standard tools available in both QGIS and Unreal Engine, without relying on any plugins.

Without a plugin will be hard, but with GDAL (QGIS uses) you can take shapefiles and export to unreal engine https://github.com/iwer/ShpGeometry/blob/master/README.md

Will the plugin support version 5.4 in the future?
